# OwnCloud Remove all files prompt

Tags: prompt, owncloud

I have a owncloud server and the owncloud desktop client.What I want to do is to be able to delete things server wise and have it automatically delete from the pc. The problem is that the owncloud client displays a warning message of "Remove All Files"? with the choices of Remove all files or to keep files when the files are deleted from the server. Is there a way to not have the prompt come up and automatically remove all files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the version 2.2.3 (maybe earlier), you can change the configuration file to disable the prompt.

See the [code where the prompt is invoked](https://github.com/owncloud/client/blob/e6d3a5a2521561330ccd9bf728ea8668cd39587a/src/gui/folder.cpp#L971) and the [code showing the configuration file property](https://github.com/owncloud/client/blob/522f7afa9ebd4686a3d4881f5bf7f867c4d7ecae/src/libsync/configfile.cpp#L47).

If you edit (on Windows): `c:\Users\myuser\AppData\Owncloud\owncloud.cfg` and add the following, under the `[General]` section, you will no longer get the prompt.

`promptDeleteAllFiles=false`

Answer (score 2):

The short answer: You cannot change this currently.

The long answer: The dialog was added as a safe-guard because there were cases where you could lose all your files unintentionally, e.g. if your admin re-created your account and left it empty. The client would assume the files had gone and would replicate this (it could not know better), so it would replicate the data removal locally. The code is still there today just to be safe.

If you are fearless, you can patch `Folder::slotAboutToRemoveAllFiles()`. Alternatively, you could open a bug report so we can solve this for everyone. What is your motivation to be able to do this without a prompt?

PS: The sources can be found on GitHub. URL and build instructions at http://doc.owncloud.org/desktop/1.5/building.html.

Comment: Actually - is this option also work on a single file ? I dont want the owncloud client EVER to delete anything on my computer !!

Comment: No. This is not possible without changing code. We're also not planning to implement this.

Comment: The code referenced, at least in latest version (2.2.3) of the client, shows that the feature can be turned off through a configuration file... https://github.com/owncloud/client/blob/e6d3a5a2521561330ccd9bf728ea8668cd39587a/src/gui/folder.cpp#L971

Answer (score 0):

I have a script that processes the files that someone drops into ownCloud and it will then move them to the final storage place.  However, this prompt stops the client from syncing until I manually log in to acknowledge it...  I guess I will learn how to patch this..  Dropbox doesn't do this.  Google Drive doesn't do this.  But since I can't use cloud services (compliance issues), I have to use this solution until I can build a new secure upload means.